# How to reference the NEW root of the database in the rule expression?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

To illustrate my use case, consider a two-way relationship between users and groups. Users can belong to a group, and groups comprise a list of users.

```json
{
  "users": {
    "alovelace": {
      "name": "Ada Lovelace",
      "groupId": "techpioneers",
    },
    "eclarke": {
      "name": "Edmund M. Clarke"
    },
    // ...
  },
  "groups": {
    "techpioneers": {
      "name": "Historical Tech Pioneers",
      "members": {
        "alovelace": true,
        "ghopper": true
      }
    },
    // ...
  }
}
```

To associate `eclarke` to a group, the client should update both paths (`/users/eclarke/groupId` and `/groups/techpioneers/members/eclarke`) in a single update so that there's no intermidiate invalid state.

To ensure this, I set the security rules for each path to reference each other:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$userId": {
        "groupId": {
          ".validate": "newData.parent().parent().parent().child('groups').child(newData.val()).child('members').hasChild($userId)"
        }
      }
    },
    "groups": {
      "$groupId": {
        "members": {
          "$memberId": {
            ".validate": "newData.parent().parent().parent().child('users').child($memberId).child('groupId').val() === $groupId"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I cannot use `root` here becaue I would be looking at old database state.

Is there a better way to do this? (without having to make multiple `.parent()` calls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no `newRoot` variable, which would solve the multiple `parent` calls. That concept *was* added in the Bolt security rules language, but since it was never added to the regular JSON language, Bolt also compiles it down to the required number of `parent` calls.

So for the moment, what you have it the correct way to do this. It would not be a bad idea to [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/), as it may have been a while since the team saw this request.